# Is it possible to make a Polish space Polisher?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $τ⊆σ$ are two topologies on a set $M$. Is it possible for $(M,τ)$ and $(M,σ)$ to be both Polish spaces?

In other words, if $(M,d_1)$ and $(M,d_2)$ are complete separable metric spaces, is it possible that the topology induced by $d_1$ is strictly finer or strictly coarser than the one induced by $d_2$?

**A special case.** Can we find a topologically stronger or weaker metric $d$ than the usual one on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is a complete separable metric space?

Comment: Not quite as good as the answer below. But what came to my mind is the set $M=\{1/n \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$ once with the discrete metric and once with the metric it inherits from $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

Whenever $(X,\tau)$ is a Polish space and $B\subseteq X$ is a Borel set we can find a topology $\sigma$ on $X$ such that:

- $\tau\subseteq\sigma$,
- $(X,\sigma)$ is a Polish space
- $B$ is clopen in $\sigma$
- $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\sigma)$ have the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra

This is easy to do in specific cases, for example when $B$ is closed. In that case you can check that if $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $\tau$, then taking as $\sigma$ the topology whose basis is given by $\mathcal B\cup\{A\cap F\mid A\in\mathcal B\}$ works (indeed this is the same as taking $(X\setminus F)\sqcup F$ with the disjoint union topology).

In particular putting on $\Bbb R$ the disjoint union topology obtained by thinking about $\Bbb R$ as $(\Bbb R\setminus[0,1])\sqcup[0,1]$ gives a Polish topology on $\Bbb R$ finer than the usual one. For an explicit complete metric on the latter example let $d_1$ be the usual Euclidean distance on $[0,1]$ and let $d_2$ be any bounded complete metric on $\Bbb R$ inducing the Euclidean topology (such as $d_2(x,y)=\min\{1,|x-y|\}$). Then $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
d_1(x,y) & x,y\in[0,1] \\
d_2(x,y) & x,y\in\Bbb R\setminus[0,1] \\
2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
is a complete metric inducing on $\Bbb R$ the disjoint union topology of $(\Bbb R\setminus[0,1])\sqcup[0,1]$

Comment: This means that if $X$ is uncountable, then there's no maximal Polish topology on $X$, but there are uncountable chains of Polish topologies with no upper bound. Indeed, every Polish topology on $X$ must have a point which isn't open (otherwise it's the discrete topology, not separable), but you can make it open in a finer Polish topology. Interesting. I wonder if there's a minimal such topology now...

Comment: @Human at least in some cases the answer is positive. If $(X,\tau)$ is compact Polish than no coarser topology is Polish, in fact no coarser topology is even Hausdorff! So the question becomes whether every Polish topology contains a compact Polish topology, I don't know the answer to this question unfortunately